# Cross-platform file names and wxString::ToStdString()

Tags: c++, unicode, wxwidgets, stdstring

I want to handle files in a cross-platform application using wxWidgets 3.1. I rely on some functions that only accept the file name as an `std::string`.

On Windows, I can simply use `wxString::ToStdString()` and everything is fine.

On Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), the conversion fails and returns an empty string when there are "special" characters in the file name or path (e.g., the default downloads directory on a French Ubuntu "Téléchargement").

When I specify the following converter explicitly on Linux, the conversion succeeds: `std::string str = wxs.ToStdString(wxMBConvUTF8());`

But this does not work on Windows and scrambles the "special" characters.

I guess, I could write platform-dependent code to deal with this, but that defeats the purpose of the toolkit.

I have done quite a bit of research on this but I am utterly confused now. I thought `wxString` uses `std::string` under the hood in a Unicode wxWidgets build (which I am using)? Why is this (apparently) platform-dependent? What am I missing?

Here is a minimal example that will pop up three messageboxes: The first one shows the `wxString` correctly, the second one shows no string (because the conversion fails), the third one shows the string once the conversion is done explicitly. On Windows, the first two boxes show the string correctly and the last one shows the wrong characters for the two 'é'.

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <fstream>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);

private:
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);


bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    if (!wxApp::OnInit())
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}


// Some file I/O function
std::string openFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (file)
    {
        return "Success!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failure!";
    }

}

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    wxString name = wxFileSelector("Pick a file");  // Pick a file with a "special" character in the name, e.g. Äréa.txt

    wxMessageBox(openFile(name.ToStdString()));  // Success! on Windows; Failure! on Linux

    wxMessageBox(openFile(std::string(name.ToUTF8())));  // Failure! on Windows; Success! on Linux
}
```

EDIT:
I found out that there was this recent addition to wxWidgets (in 3.1.5):

> Add wxString::utf8_string() This adds a yet another conversion
> function, which is not ideal, but still better than having to write
> ToStdString(wxConvUTF8) every time for losslessly converting wxString
> to std::string: not only this is too long, but it's also too easy to
> forget to specify wxConvUTF8, resulting in data loss when using
> non-UTF-8 locale.

So you would think that clears it up. BUT I *am* using a UTF-8 locale! This is the output of the `locale` command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT2: I changed the minimal example to something closer to what I am actually trying to do.

EDIT3: I changed the example to something *even* closer to what I am actually trying to do. :-)

Comment: can you change the function implementation? I would probably try to use std::wstring instead... Failing that - I will probably write platform dependent code. The function you rely on is not UNICODE aware.

Comment: But std::string can handle UTF-8, which should be enough here. That's why it is working on Windows, I assume. Why is it not working on Linux?

Comment: I also think `std::string str = wxs.utf8_str();` should work on all platforms.  Can you see if that works?

Comment: @Simon, are you sure it is UTF-8? Remember Windows native string is UTF-16...

Comment: That is true, but the STL string is still UTF-8 and should be portable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/c-unicode-encoding-conversions-with-stl-strings-and-win32-apis#converting-between-utf-8-and-utf-16-using-win32-apis

Comment: @NewPagodi The ``wxString::utf8_str()`` function also garbles the special characters, but it led me to some other discovery. Please see the edited question for more details.

Comment: Are you calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` or a C++ equivalent at the beginning of the program? If you are not, you should.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I did not call that! The locale is managed by wxLocale (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_locale.html) in wxWidgets. I manually initialized it using the system default and now ``wxString::ToStdString()`` converts correctly! I don't understand why this does not happen by default, but I guess you have to set it explicitly! Would you like to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it? And maybe use the above link to point people to the right class to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the function `wxString::ToStdString()` uses the encoding of the current locale of the program.

The default locale of the program is not the locale set in the user environment. All C and C++ programs start in a locale named "C". In order to use the locale specified in the user environment, one needs to call

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

at the beginning of the program. C++ has its own method of doing this

```
 std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

but sometimes it doesn't work, presumably because of bugs in the C++ standard library implementation, so the C way is more reliable.

If your framework has its own method of dealing with locales, you should probably use it instead.

Comment: I realized that this works, but has some side effects that may introduce other problems. Changing the locale may also change the decimal sign, for example.

Comment: Yes it will set the decimal sign to what the user wanted.

Comment: Which sounds like a good idea, but when your program interacts with text files of some kind (e.g. XML) that contains decimal numbers, the parsing becomes more complicated.

Comment: Each stream can be imbued with its own locale, also research locale facets.

Comment: I did end up using this solution but with a slight modification so that only the encoding is changed: ``setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");``

Answer (score 3):

"Functions that accept file names as `std::string`" must accept them in UTF-8, so you need to use `wxString::utf8_str()` or its synonym `ToUTF8()` rather than relying on the current locale encoding as you do currently. In any case, you still need to pass the result to `std::string` ctor as these functions return `char*` pointers or buffers.

In the latest 3.1 version of wxWidgets you also have `wxString::utf8_string()` which directly returns an UTF-8-encoded `std::string` and is thus more convenient to use.

Comment: Calling ``ToUTF8()`` works on Linux, but does not seem to work on Windows. The "special" characters are garbled. However, ``ToStdString()`` returns a proper representation. But I should not have to write platform-dependent code for this, right?

Comment: `ToUTF8()` definitely works. If you get unexpected output, it means that your string already contains garbage when you call `ToUTF8()`, i.e. you're probably filling it incorrectly too (in particular, if you create it from UTF-8-encoded string, you'd better use `FromUTF8()` as well instead of relying on the current encoding being UTF-8 which is never the case under Windows).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just can't get it to work. Please see the minimal example in my post above.

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself with the use of `auto`. Your `utfStr` is a `std::string`, so when you pass it to `wxMessageBox()`, you need to specify its encoding, i.e. do `wxMessageBox(wxString::FromUTF8(utfStr))`, otherwise you're again using the current locale encoding instead of UTF-8. Again, the rules are simple: by default all `char*` strings use the current locale encoding, you must use `{To,From}UTF8()` explicitly for UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am being obtuse or if I am spreading confusion by changing the example, but I still don't get it. I understand now that I need to use ``{To,From}UTF8()`` to convert back and forth between an UTF8 encoded `std::string` and `wxString`. But the discussion moved away from what I actually want to know (which I am sure is because of the confusing way I posed the example): Why do I need platform-dependent conversions when dealing with unwrapped file I/O functions (see the updated example)?

Comment: The answer to your question is simple but not really helpful: you need it because your default locale encoding differs between Linux and MSW. With modern MSW versions you can actually use UTF-8 under it too, finally, but it's arguably still simpler to just be explicit about which strings are in UTF-8 and which are not. Or use wide strings.

Comment: So the ultimate solution to my problem would be something like (?):
``#ifdef WIN32 openFile(name.ToStdString()); #else  openFile(name.ToUTF8()); #endif
``

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how did you deduce this from any of my comments, in particular the last but one in which I mention 2 solutions that are both better than this one. But, just to be clear, if by "ultimate" you mean "not far from the worst", then yes. Otherwise, no, this is not the best solution. To be **very** clear: either you use narrow strings and **always** use UTF-8 for all of them **or** you use wide strings.

Comment: I'm sorry I continue to confuse. My problem is that I cannot seem to translate what you are saying into code. Maybe I am just being daft, but I promise, I am trying to understand. If I use narrow strings in UTF-8 for the file name, ``std::ifstream`` fails to open the file on Windows. If I use wide strings, ``std::ifstream`` does not have a matching ctor on Linux.

Comment: OK, `ifstream` is indeed special. The simplest and best solution for dealing with it is to use C++17 `std::filesystem::path` which should work correctly everywhere. Otherwise you have to use `wxString::fn_str()` which hides the difference between platforms for you by returning narrow string under Unix and wide string under Mac, so you can pass it to (non-standard) `fstream` ctor taking wide string under Windows.

Comment: Apologies if I am misunderstanding once again, but the ``std::filesystem::path`` ctor needs a string, which again means I need to convert the ``wxString`` to different formats depending on the platform. And ``wxString::fn_str()`` only avoids platform-dependent code if I can pass the result directly to the ``std::ifstream`` ctor. In my case, the call to ``std::ifstream`` is inside a third-party function that only accepts a narrow string (similar to the above example).

Comment: You won't be able to open all files under Windows if you use narrow strings unless you set the locale to UTF-8, wx or not. You must do one or the other to be able to work with any file.

Comment: I see. I changed the locale in the wxApp derived class' ``OnInit()`` function to "C.UTF-8". That way I don't have to change any other code and it seems to work now on both Linux and Windows. Thank you for your help and especially patience!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `wxString::fn_str()`, which returns a suitable string in a suitable type to be used as a filename.

If you use `wxString::ToStdString()` on Windows, everything is no longer "fine" if you have e.g. cyrillic letters in the string and your locale is German. The conversion fails.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards that! There are two reasons why I don't think it really solves my issue, though: That function does not return an ``std::string`` so I additionally need to pass its result to an ``std::string`` constructor. The second reason is that the problem does not only extend to filenames, although that was the trigger that made me realize that something is wrong. But this definitely lets me write a workaround and if no better answer comes up, I will accept this one.

Comment: Also, passing the result of ``wxString::fn_str()`` to an ``std::string`` constructor only seems to work on Linux but not on Windows.